# How to get a label caption to be set in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

This is my first time with creating a UserForm.
I've looked for solutions, but as yet have not found one that works.

I am trying to set the caption for a couple of labels. I want them set when the form opens.

I have this right now(In the UserForms code:

```
Private Sub Budget_Initialize()
    Me.Label25.Caption = Format(Month(Now), "mmmm")
    Me.Label26.Caption = Format(Month(Now) + 1, "mmmm")
    Me.Caption = "Test, Test, Test!"
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried this too(In the ThisWorkbook code):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Budget.Show
    With Budget
        .Label25.Caption = Format(Month(Now), "mmmm")
        .Label26.Caption = Format(Month(Now) + 1, "mmmm")
        .Caption = "Test, Test, Test!"
    End With
    Budget.Repaint
End Sub
```

It opens the UserForm when I open the workbook, but it doesn't update the captions.

I want the captions to be the names of this month and next month.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I don't get an error, just nothing updates they both just have their names showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event routine you need (independent of the name of the form)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ....
End Sub
```

So basically, just rename `Budget_Initialize()` to `UserForm_Initialize()`

Answer (score 2):

Format(Month(Now), "mmmm") will always be January, as it is maximally Format(12, "mmmm"). Skip month, Now alone is what you need.